# Error when using Nx with PrimeNG table component

Tags: angular, primeng, primeng-datatable, nomachine-nx

I created a brand new Nx workspace using `npx create-nx-workspace@latest` and installed PrimeNG using `npm install primeng --save`

Then, I tried to import `TableModule` in `app.module.ts` file of the generated app:

```
import { TableModule } from 'primeng/table';

@NgModule({
  declarations: [AppComponent, NxWelcomeComponent],
  imports: [BrowserModule, TableModule],
  providers: [],
  bootstrap: [AppComponent],
})
export class AppModule {}
```

I'm getting the following error:

> ./apps/newapp/src/main.ts - Error: Module build failed (from
> ./node_modules/@ngtools/webpack/src/ivy/index.js): Error: Cannot
> resolve type entity i5.ScrollingModule to symbol
> at C:\Users\daudkhan\code\test\test\node_modules@ngtools\webpack\src\ivy\loader.js:77:18
> at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:96:5)

[Here's](https://stackblitz.com/edit/github-camb2v) the stackblitz

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to install angular/cdk

`npm install @angular/cdk`